# Deutsches Äquivalent zum englischen »Feature Request«

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, single-word-request

[Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature-Request) und [Leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/feature%20request) schlagen mir *Leistungsmerkmalanforderung* als Übersetzung für *Feature Request* vor, das erscheint mir aber etwas plump und umständlich, darüber hinaus ist mir dieses Wort noch nie über den Weg gelaufen.

Gibt es einen passenderen deutschen Begriff, oder hat *Feature Request* im Bereich der Software-Entwicklung (beispielsweise *feature requests* bei *Meta StackExchange*) mittlerweile soweit Einzug in die deutsche Sprache erhalten dass man es getrost bei offizieller Kommunikation verwenden kann?

Comment: Bitte gib an, von welchem Industrie- oder Wirtschaftszweig du sprichst. Das angemessene Wort kann unterschiedlich sein je nach dem.

Comment: Wörterbücher haben den Nachteil, dass sie ein Wort mit einem anderen übersetzen müssen und dabei fürchterliche Würmer erzeugen. Im Deutschen würde man eher mehrere Worte verwenden.

Comment: @tofro: *Wörterbücher haben den Nachteil, dass sie ein Wort mit einem anderen übersetzen müssen* – Das stimmt weder logisch noch erfahrungsmäßig. Wenn überhaupt, muss ein Ausdruck mit einem anderen Ausdruck übersetzt werden; der kann aber mehrere Wörter enthalten.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft *Leistungsmerkmalanforderung* ist doch ein wunderschönes Beispiel, für das, was ich meine? Ich glaube nicht, dass irgendjemand irgendwo im deutschen Sprachraum sowas auch nur denkt, geschweige denn sagt.

Comment: @tofro: Ja, aber das ist nicht irgendwelchen inhärenten Einschränkungen an Wörterbücher geschuldet. Die können auch anders.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Dann lass' es mich genauer formulieren: *Manche **meinen** irrtümlicherweise, sie müssten* - Und dann kommt sowas dabei raus.

Comment: @tofro: Dem kann ich mich auch anschließen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich spreche vom Bereich der Softwareentwicklung (siehe aktualisierte Antwort). Mit war die breitere Verwendung des englischen Begriffes nicht bekannt, danke für den Hinweis.

Comment: Fraglich ist, was die "Leistung" in dem Vorschlag soll. Eine Merkmalsanforderung trifft es m.E. besser. Das Merkmal besagt aber auch nicht viel. Eine Anforderung wird immer ein oder mehrere Merkmale betreffen. Dass diese etwas leisten sollen ist auch nicht überraschend. Bei "gibt's das auch in gelb?" vielleicht nicht, außer man geht so weit zu sagen, dass es geschmacklich etwas für Freunde gelber Produkte leistet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Ich nehme an, du beziehst dich auf Software)

Bevor die englische Sprache so stark in die Softwareentwicklung eingezogen ist wie heute, verwendete man in meinem beruflichen Umfeld ganz einfach den Begriff

> Änderungswunsch

und nahm selbstverständlich implizit an, dass eine *Änderung* nicht einfach nur "anders", sondern gleichzeitig auch "besser" oder "leistungsfähiger" wäre. Der englische Begriff ist zwar treffender, die Exaktheit ist hier meiner Meinung nach aber nicht absolut notwendig, weil man Änderungen eben normalerweise nicht macht, um Leistungsmerkmale zu entfernen...

Im Englischen gibt es den dazu passenden Begriff

> change request

als Oberbegriff, der den *feature request* mit beinhaltet.

Comment: Ein change request ist aber nicht dasselbe wie ein feature request.

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet Hat ja auch keiner behauptet?

Comment: Ach so? - So habe ich Deine Antwort verstanden. Oder sollte mit der Antwort erst gar nicht die Frage "Deutsches Äquivalent zum englischen »Feature Request«" beantwortet werden?

Comment: In der Tat, ein *feature request* sollte nach Adam Riese etwas anderes meinen als ein *change request*. Der **Änderungswunsch** meinte eben den Wunsch, etwas zu ändern, das schon besteht; das **Leistungsmerkmal** (nennen wir es mal so) dagegen bezieht sich primär auf eine geforderte Eigenschaft eines erst noch zu erzeugenden Endprodukts. Solche Leistungsmerkmale werden oft in einer **Merkmalsliste** oder auch, ganz klassisch ingenieurssprachlich, in einem **Pflichtenheft** festgehalten. Letzteres ist auch in der Software-Branche ein bekannter Begriff.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "das **Leistungsmerkmal** (nennen wir es mal so) dagegen bezieht sich primär auf eine geforderte Eigenschaft eines erst noch zu erzeugenden Endprodukts." - ich stimme dir zu, dass sich ein Änderungswunsch auf eine Änderung an etwas bereits Bestehendem (einer bestehenden Funktion) bezieht. *Feature Requests* sind aber häufig genau diejenigen Anforderungen nach zusätzlichen Funktionen, die über den ursprünglichen Funktionsumfang eines *bereits bestehenden* Produkts hinausgehen.

Answer (score 11):

In der Softwareentwicklungabteilung des Vereins für deutsche Sprache und in der begriffspräzisierenden Beamtensphäre ist "Leistungsmerkmalanforderung" sicherlich die beliebteste zur Auswahl stehende Möglichkeit.

In den meisten Fällen tut's auch der **Verbesserungsvorschlag.**

---

<sub>Update zum Update in der Frage:

Anglizismen sind in der sprachlichen Umgebung von Softwareentwicklern absolut gängig. Hatte die ursprüngliche Frage so verstanden, ob der in der Software-Szene gängige Begriff auch in anderen Fällen angemessen verwendbar wäre. Im nun bezeichneten sprachlichen Umfeld ist die direkte Übernahme von *Feature Request* sogar wesentlich häufiger anzutreffen als Eindeutschungen, Alternativbegriffe oder Übersetzungen. „Änderungswunsch“ oder eben „Verbesserungsvorschlag“ sollten aber auch dort im Spektrum von unauffällige bis hübsche Variante verwendbar sein.</sub>

Comment: Nur in der Softwareszene sagt man Featurerequest. +1 Verbesserungsvorschläge gab es aber natürlich auch schon vorher in der deutschsprachigen Kultur, also muss es dafür auch Ausdrücke geben (Gulaschrezepte, Super-8-Kameras, ...).

Comment: ggf. trifft es _Änderungsvorschlag, Ergänzungsvorschlag, Erweiterungsvorschlag_ besser

Answer (score 5):

Ein universell einsetzbarer Ausdruck wäre einfach

> geforderte Eigenschaft

aber viele Sprachnutzer, besonders in Wirtschaftszusammenhängen, werden einen Ausdruck suchen, der mehr "fachmännisch" klingt. In diesem Fall wäre

> Merkmalsanforderung

schon genug.

Für mehr Ausdrücke müsste man erst mal wissen, von welchem Kontext (welcher Branche) die Rede ist.

Nachtrag: Nachdem klar wurde, dass es hier um die Software-Branche geht: Ich denke,

> Leistungsmerkmal

ist durchaus verwendbar, wenn auch "Leistungsmerkmalsanforderung" zu lang und bürokratisch ist.

In Gebrauch ist das aus dem Ingenieursjargon kommende

> Pflichtenheft

was jedoch die Gesamtheit der gewünschten Eigenschaften eines Endprodukts bezeichnet oder eben die Gesamtheit der

> Produktmerkmale

oder einfach eben

> Eigenschaften

oder auch

> Spezifikationen

was ich gefühlsmäßig eher in Branchen wie Maschinenbau und Leichtindustrie inklusive Textil verortet hätte, aber offenbar kommt es inzwischen auch in der Softwarebranche vor (siehe Min-Soos Kommentar unten).

Comment: "Spezifikation" ist in der Software-Industrie durchaus gebräuchlich und hat den Begriff "Pflichtenheft" schon vor etwa 10 Jahren abgelöst.

Comment: @Min-Soo. Habe die Antwort entsprechend leicht umformuliert.

Comment: Und den _request_ lassen wir unter dem Teppich verschwinden?

Comment: @user unknown. Hm... ich hatte unterstellt, dass der geneigte Leser, nachdem einmal oben "geforderte Eigenschaften" und auch "Merkmalsanforderung" erwähnt waren, in weiteren Wortvorschlägen die entsprechende Ergänzung selbst vornehmen würde können?

Comment: Die meisten der Vorschläge klingen irgendwie viel zu "verbindlich". Ein "request" ist zunächst mal nur eine Anfrage bzw. Bitte. Ob sich der Anbieter verpflichtet, dieser Bitte nachzukommen (und sie damit zu einer Anforderung, also einem "requirement", erhebt), ergibt sich aus dem Kontext, ist im Begriff "feature request" aber nicht unbedingt enthalten.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Hast Du?

Answer (score 4):

Das Wort *Feature* ist im Zusammenhang mit Software schon seit vielen Jahren eingedeutscht. Das würde ich daher nicht übersetzen.

*Request* ist Bestandteil des auch im Deutschen längst etablierten Ausdrucks [*Change Request*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%84nderungsanforderung). Allerdings ist ein *Change Request* in der Regel etwas anderes als ein *Feature Request* oder hat zumindest eine Zusatzbedeutung. Ein *Change Request* bedeutet in der Regel nicht einfach nur, dass an der Software etwas gemacht, sondern dass an der Software eben etwas *geändert* werden soll - also eine Änderung eines schon *bestehenden* Features. Wenn sich der Auftraggeber also überlegt hat, dass ein von ihm ursprünglich bestelltes und spezifiziertes Feature nun doch anders ausgestaltet werden soll. Die Bezeichnung *Change Request* wird dann in der Regel benutzt um zu verdeutlichen, dass es sich um eine Änderung handelt, die eine Kostenpflicht über den bisher vereinbarten Umfang hinaus auslöst. Deswegen gibt es mitunter endlose Diskussion darüber, ob ein Wunsch einen neuen Auftrag, ein *Change Request* oder einfach nur die Umsetzung der bereits ausgehandelten Spezifikation darstellt - denn die Entscheidung darüber entscheidet über Geld.

Ich würde *Feature Request* ins Deutsche entweder unverändert übernehmen (siehe auch den deutschsprachigen Wikipedia-Artikel ["Feature-Request"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature-Request)) oder höchstens das *Request* - je nach Kontext verschieden - übersetzen. Meine Vorschläge wären demnach:

> Feature-Request
>   Feature-Anfrage
>   Feature-Wunsch
>   Feature-Vorschlag
>   Feature-Bestellung